# Makefile set variable in recipe and call another recipe

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I need to add a rule where a recipe sets a variable to a value and calls another recipe.

I need something like:

```
foo-a:
        $(eval MY_VAR=a)
        goto foo recipe

foo-b:
        $(eval MY_VAR=b)
        goto foo recipe

foo:
        Do something that uses MY_VAR
```

How do I go about doing this? I don't think it would be correct to recursively call $(MAKE) since there may be multiple rules passed on the command line.

Comment: This is not possible.  It fundamentally misunderstands make: makefile is not a procedural language and targets are not functions that can be called (the closest you can come is, as you suggest, recursively invoking make).  Since you don't actually say why you want to do this we can't give you any advice on a better way to write your makefile.